# how do I link a c file to two executables

Tags: c, makefile

I have a file called wrapsock.c that has several wrapper functions for the socket.h header file. I have two executables, FTP_client and FTP_server who both need to use the wrapsock.c file. I am having trouble with my makefile to link the wrapsock.c file to both of these programs

Here is my makefile below:

```
all: ./bin/FTP_client ./bin/FTP_server

bin/FTP_client: main_client.o wrapsock.o
    gcc -o bin/FTP_client main_client.o wrapsock.o -lpthread -g
    mv main_client.o ./bin
    mv wrapsock.o ./bin

bin/FTP_server: main_server.o wrapsock.o
    gcc -o bin/FTP_server main_server.o wrapsock.o -lpthread -g
    mv main_server.o ./bin
    mv wrapsock.o ./bin

main_client.o: src/main_client.c
    gcc -c src/main_client.c -g

wrapsock.o: src/wrapsock.c src/wrapsock.h
    gcc -c src/wrapsock.c -g

main_server.o: src/main_server.c
    gcc -c src/main_server.c -g

clean:
    rm ./bin/*.o
    rm ./bin/FTP_client
    rm ./bin/FTP_server
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
gcc -c src/main_client.c -g
gcc -c src/wrapsock.c -g
gcc -o bin/FTP_client main_client.o wrapsock.o -lpthread -g
mv main_client.o ./bin
mv wrapsock.o ./bin
gcc -o bin/FTP_server main_server.o wrapsock.o -lpthread -g
gcc: error: wrapsock.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [makefile:9: bin/FTP_server] Error 1
```

Comment: Make thinks it has made `wrapsock.o`, so it doesn't need to rebuild it when compiles the second program that uses it — but you've moved it out of the way for no obvious reason.  This confuses the system — don't do it.

Comment: you can 1) build the object files directly into _bin_ rather than to move them, or 2) never put the objects under _bin_ (edited answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mv wrapsock.o ./bin
gcc -o bin/FTP_server main_server.o wrapsock.o -lpthread -g
gcc: error: wrapsock.o: No such file or directory
```

To move the object is not a good way, create the objects  directly into the directory bin as you do for the executable :

```
all: ./bin/FTP_client ./bin/FTP_server

bin/FTP_client:  bin/main_client.o  bin/wrapsock.o
    gcc -o bin/FTP_client bin/main_client.o bin/wrapsock.o -lpthread -g

bin/FTP_server:  bin/main_server.o  bin/wrapsock.o
    gcc -o bin/FTP_server  bin/main_server.o  bin/wrapsock.o -lpthread -g

bin/main_client.o: src/main_client.c
    gcc -c src/main_client.c -g -o bin/main_client.o

bin/wrapsock.o: src/wrapsock.c src/wrapsock.h
    gcc -c src/wrapsock.c -g -o bin/wrapsock.o

bin/main_server.o: src/main_server.c
    gcc -c src/main_server.c -g -o bin/main_server.o

clean:
    rm ./bin/*.o
    rm ./bin/FTP_client
    rm ./bin/FTP_server
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why are you moving the binary objects to `bin/`, but after you've built your client target `wrapsock.o` is no longer in project root and resides in `bin/` instead, so when server target gets its turn, gcc can no longer find it. I would just ditch the moves or if there is a reason for performing them, do so in a separate target that is done only after both binaries have been built (i.e. lists them as prerequisites).